# Customize plugin templates

Tags: plugins, customization, filters, templates, hooks

I am attempting to make some pretty serious template customizations to some of my plugins (mostly [Event Espresso](https://eventespresso.com/)).

Obviously I don’t want to touch the core stylesheets and template files, since they’ll be wiped whenever an upgrade comes along. All I’m trying to do is shuffle around and expand on the structure within my child theme, and in the case of some of the plugins, output some custom field boxes.

What would be the easiest and most brain-dead simple way to go about this? Hooks and filters? I have an elementary grasp on them, but anything to get me going in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. I just want my template modifications to be separated from the core files so they survive updates . . . so pointing the plugins to my custom templates, more or less. I assume this is probably a functions.php thing, but I'm lost.

Thank you very much!

Comment: if you want to customise a plugin, the better way to do that is to create a new plugin that unhook or filter the hooks of the original plugin. the first step is to analyse the PHP code to find which hook make what you want to modify..

Comment: The degree to which plugin *templates* are customisable depends entirely on the plugin and what level of customisation it supports. You should contact Event Espresso support, or consult its developer documentation.

Comment: Agree with Jacob. You can start here: https://eventespresso.com/section/templates-2/